# Correct way to call Howler onend() method

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, syntax-error, howler.js

I'm trying to use the Howler on end method to update some properties after a track finishes, but it's not working properly. Code like this:

```
var track_number = 0;

var sound = new Howl({
    src: ["barking.mp3"],
    autoplay: false;
    volume: 0.5;
    onload: function() {
        console.log("LOADED");
    }
});

sound.onend() {
    track_number ++;
    $("#xxxjukeboxpicture".attr("src", "/tile" + track_number + ".jpg");
};
```

Every time I try to add the `sound.onend()` function in and run this the browser throws an error saying there is a missing semi-colon on the `sound.onend()` line. Can someone clarify the correct syntax here?

Comment: i think you might need something more like `sound.onend(function(event){...});`  (what you have is not syntactically correct)

Comment: What event parameter would the function within the `.onend` method-call take? `.onend` is only called in the event of a track ending, so should not need additional event parameters, as far as I can tell. I'll try with the function call nested within the method, though, see if that helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to do the following:

```
sound.on('end', function(){
  track_number ++;
  $("#xxxjukeboxpicture".attr("src", "/tile" + track_number + ".jpg");
});
```

Based on Howler docs: https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js#documentation

Comment: Interesting! I had been looking at the Howler website and had assumed that the GitHub info would be the same as the website info. Good find!

Comment: @TheMasterPriest I assume you were looking at the old website, which is showing docs for 1.x. The new website is http://howlerjs.com.

Answer (score 3):

This is  an old thread. But I have just been looking at howler..

The on events need to be part of the new howler object as optionals.

So the reason you get this error is because you are not adding onend as such but trying to add it independently.   I assume `sound.on('end'` works because it is using the browser API rather than Howler's.

The correct way for the options and events is:

```
var sound = new Howl({
    src: ["barking.mp3"],
     preload: true,
    autoplay: false,
    onload: function() {
        console.log("LOADED");
    },
   onend: function() {
          console.log("ONEND");  
    }
});
```